# Spring and session timeout on JBoss

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jboss

I want to setup session timeout to 15 minutes. I set `server.session.timeout` to `900` and it works when I run the app in the provided Tomcat. However, when I deploy the application on the JBoss session timeout doesn't occur after 15 minutes. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you share your web.xml or the code where you configured the timeout ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In spring boot `server.session.timeout` is in minutes not seconds.

In your `web.xml`, number is in minutes.

```
<web-app ...>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>20</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Comment: I think that server.session.timeout property does not apply on JBoss, since I had it set to 900, but the session expired after 30 minutes...

Comment: You need to override the deault https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HttpSessionTimeout

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring Boot, you can add the below property to your `WEB-INF/application.properties` (if you don't have one, create it under `WEB-INF` folder):

```
server.session.timeout=900
```

For more details on `application.properties`, you can refer the below link:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html